# How the default value initialized even not specified in explicit constructor in c#

Tags: c#

Declared variable and not initialized in explicit constructor. Then how the default value initialized to the variable.is it initialization done by the implicit constructor?

Ex:

```
class A
{
    int i;
    public A()
    {
    }  
}

class program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A a = new A();
        Console.Write(a.i);
    }
}
```

Output: 
0

Comment: As Sean says, class members always gets initialized, its local variables that need initialization.

Comment: Nice guarantee that the CLR provides, class members get initialized to their default value.

Comment: Thank for reply and what i have understand about the constructor is, if the class doesn't have the explicit constructor then the implicit constructor will initialize the default values to the global variables. in this case explicit constructor not initialing then the implicit constructor is doing that?

Answer (score 4):

If you don't initialize a member variable then it gets assigned the value `default(T)` where `T` is the type.

For reference types this is `null`. For `bool` it is `false` and for other value types it is whatever the state of the object would be it the memory for it was zeron-initialized. Thus for `int` it it `0`.

Comment: Thank for reply and what i have understand about the constructor is if the class doesn't have the explicit constructor then the implicit constructor will initialize the default values to the variables. in this case explicit constructor not initialing then the implicit constructor is doing that?

Comment: @karthi - No. It's not about whether of not you have a constructor, it's about whether or not you assign something to the member variable. Inside the body of your `A` constructor `i` is already `0`

Comment: If you don't provide a constructor for your class, C# creates one by default that instantiates the object and sets member variables to the default values.  The statement from "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors". Here i am getting confused. in my example who assigning the value?

Comment: @karthi - It doesn't matter if you add a default constructor or not, member variables will always be initialized to their default values unless you explicitly assign a value when declaring the member variable.

Answer (score 0):

int is a value type and cannot be null unless you declare it as a nullable int (int?). It’s default value is 0.

Answer (score 0):

you have taken `i` as `int`, and Integer is value type with a default value is `0`

Check below link, if you're new in C#

[Default Value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/default-values)

[Value Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-types)

[Reference Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types)

Use `?`, If you don't want to assign a default value. see below example

[image]